# Is there is any way to see the code line running during the app

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to see my code lines that are running during my app testing in the emulator  and developing with android studio

[image]io

Comment: Android Studio has a debugger.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-studio.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click on the Debugger button button shown in the image, to start the app on the device in debug mode

[image: Debugger button]

And be sure to have break points in reachable code. like shown in the image

[image: Break point]

To create a breakpoint just click the area where pointed by the red arrow mark in the above image. Its a simple process really

Comment: the code with the break point is what i will see in the debugger true ?

Comment: yes, then you can execute line by line by pressing f10, and you can press f8 to hit the next break point

Comment: thanks for the explanation and can I use the app and the debugger list to me the code lines ?

Comment: yes when you have the device/emulator connected to the IDE, you will be able to see which code line is going to get executed next, and also have access to all the variables that are in scope at that moment

Comment: will you explain more i have attached a screenshot non of the debugger and console displays

Comment: I see that its connected successfully you havent added any break points to your code thats why

Comment: but i want to see all the excused code lines on pressing 2 for example not only on the break-pointed line

Answer (score 1):

Use the debugger to step through the code. You can step over and step into functions, set breakpoints and so on.

[See here](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/tools/debugging/debugging-studio.html)